# С помощью чего можно получать настоящие московские адреса?

Tags: api, карты, поиск-api

Нужно по запросу получать случайный реальный московский адрес в виде улица-дом. Есть ли какие-то сервисы или программы/базы для этого?

Comment: Да ГУВД/ФСБ думаю поможет. Придется ответить на несколько вопросов и там видно будет

Comment: 2GIS в помощь =)

Comment: Сергей Семёнович, перелогиньтесь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eсть свободно скачиваемая база [ФИАС](https://fias.nalog.ru/Updates) - там все есть, правда по всей России, а не только Москва.

Comment: Судя по вашему вопросу вым нужны были московские адреса. Отвечает ли ваш ответ ны ваш вопрос?

Comment: Да, там можно отфильтровать